# how do i select data from multiple columns from two tables where there is a common column in both?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

seems like a cake walk, because of the common column thing, but i've looked and i've looked and can't find the answer anywhere.  there may be very similar things people are trying to do, but everyone always needs it slightly different than how i need it.  anyway here goes...

jobs table

```
+----+--------+----+----+----+
| id | userid | i1 | i2 | i3 |
+----+--------+----+----+----+
| 1  |   1    | a  | k  | t  |
| 2  |   1    | b  | l  | u  |
| 3  |   1    | c  | m  | v  |
| 4  |   2    | d  | n  | w  |
| 5  |   2    | f  | o  | x  |
| 6  |   2    | g  | p  | y  |
| 7  |   3    | h  | q  | z  |
| 8  |   3    | i  | r  | a  |
| 9  |   4    | j  | s  | b  |
+----+--------+----+----+----+
```

user_table table

```
+--------+----+----+----+
| userid | fn | ln | i4 |
+--------+----+----+----+
|   1    | a  | b  | w  |
|   2    | c  | d  | x  |
|   3    | e  | f  | y  |
|   4    | g  | h  | z  |
+--------+----+----+----+
```

i want to select multiple columns from one table and multiple columns from another table, and the amount of columns don't have the same amount.  so if i'm selecting id, i1, i2, and i3 from jobs table and selecting fn, ln, and i4 from user_table table, then that means i'm selecting 4 pieces of info from jobs table and 3 pieces of info from user_table table.

so let's say i want to select a specific job and display the info for that job, but also i want to display the info of the user that belongs to the job then it might go something like this...

job 1:

id: 1, i1: a, i2: k, i3: t, fn: a, ln: b, i4: w

for job 4 it would be:

id: 4, i1: d, i2: n, i3: w, fn: c, ln: d, i4: x

the jobs table and user_table table have the common column of userid.  so how do i write my query to do the above using this common column?

i tried all sorts of things with SELECT and WHERE and AND and JOIN and UNION and AS and GROUP and BY and writing the table names separate from the column names and writing the table names and column names together with a period in between.  i just can't find the correct way to write this query.

in these examples below that don't work i'm just trying to select one thing from the user_table table and everything from the jobs table that isn't the userid, but i will need the ability to select multiple things from the 2nd table if needed.  so i want to select everything from first table and just certain things from second table.

doesn't work:

```
SELECT id, i1, i2, i3, i4 FROM jobs, user_table WHERE jobs.id = $id GROUP BY id
```

doesn't work:

```
SELECT * from jobs where id = $id UNION SELECT i4 from user_table where userid = $userid
```

Comment: Please read SQL tutorials about JOIN.

Comment: `SELECT jobs.*, user_table.* FROM jobs LEFT JOIN user_table ON jobs.user_id = user_table.userid` - or INNER JOIN, depending on your requirements of the results (LEFT JOIN will show ALL jobs, regardless of whether the userid matches, where as INNER JOIN will enforce a match between the two)

Comment: this one also doesn't select the correct data from 2nd table.  unless i'm not making my variables correct?  after the query how do i make variables of all the columns from different tables?  like this?  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); if($row) { $date = $row['date']; $imgurl = $row['img_url']; }  ---  the date one is from jobs table and the img one is from user_table.  when i run the whole thing, the img is the same for all the jobs and not changing depending on the user associated with the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query

```
SELECT * FROM jobs
INNER JOIN user_table on jobs.userid = user_table.userid
```

will join your jobs information with the user information. Then just add your where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs
INNER JOIN user_table on jobs.userid = user_table.userid
where jobs.id = $id
```

Comment: hmm, at first i thought this one wasn't selecting data from 2nd table either, but then it started to.  wonder if cache is messing with me.  after clearing cache i see weird issue.  works in chrome but not firefox.  all the pieces of info from 1st table are good in both browsers.  the piece of data from 2nd table is changing the way it's supposed to for different records made by different users, but is staying the same for every record on firefox.

Comment: i thought the other one was closer but this one actually was.  this one had jobs.userid = user_table.userid, which worked, the other answer had jobs.id = user_table.id --- it's not doing the different browser bug like i thought, so that's why this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to join the tables like so:

```
SELECT j.column1, j.column2, u.column5, u.column6 
FROM 
  jobs j 
INNER JOIN 
  user_table u 
ON 
  u.userid = j.userid 
WHERE 
  j.id = $id
```

Comment: this one got a result.  just needed to add a star to select everything in jobs table.  just not sure if this selects everything in user_table table as well.  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobs jobs INNER JOIN user_table user_table ON user_table.userid = jobs.userid WHERE jobs.id = $id") --- is there way to select everything in table 1 and pick and choose my columns in table 2?

Comment: Yea you can say `SELECT j.*, u.column1, u.column2 FROM ...`

Comment: i might have spoke too soon.  for the one piece of data i'm trying to select in the 2nd table, it always comes up as the same piece of data for every record when it should be different depending on the userid.  it's returning the correct column but wrong userid.

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT jobs.*, user_table.img_url FROM jobs jobs INNER JOIN user_table user_table ON user_table.userid = jobs.userid WHERE jobs.id = $id")

Comment: don't think that variable was the issue. maybe it was typing jobs twice in a row after FROM.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT id, i1, i2, i3, i4 FROM jobs 
inner join user_table on jobs.id = user_table.id WHERE jobs.id = $id GROUP BY id
```

Comment: trying to adapt it to my real column names:
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, firstname, lastname, company, img_url FROM jobs inner join user_table on jobs.id = user_table.id WHERE jobs.id = $id GROUP BY id") --- i get this error: Column 'company' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: so you have to make it un-ambiguous, choose which one you want e.g. jobs.company  Please accept my answer

Comment: a variation of yours is what ended up working.  couldn't get variations of other answers to work.  i hope cache isn't messing with me again, but anyway, here it is: SELECT jobs.*, user_table.img_url FROM jobs inner join user_table on jobs.userid = user_table.userid WHERE jobs.id = $id GROUP BY id